# how to read data from plist in tableView when no internet

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview, plist

I write array in plist from json url .
I want when not exist internet tableview get data from plist and when exist tableView get data from json url

this is my code (I create plist file in Document folder application) :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#define DOC_DIR [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]


@implementation ViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *name;
    NSMutableData *data;
    NSString *listPath;
    NSMutableArray *array;
    NSArray *n;
    NSMutableArray *add;
}
@synthesize table;
-(NSString*)Dir
{
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myDomain.com/test.php"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [con start];


}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    name = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < [name count]; i++) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.table indexPathForSelectedRow];
    n = [[name objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)+i]objectForKey:@"title"];
    if(!add){
        add = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    [add addObject:n];
    }
    NSLog(@"add = %@",add);
    [table reloadData];
    [self WriteToPlist:add];
}
- (void)WriteToPlist:(NSArray*)dataArray
{
    NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dataArray,@"Name", nil];
    NSString *Path = [DOC_DIR stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Plist.plist"];
    [dic writeToFile:Path atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"Path : %@",Path);
}
```

and this code read data from json :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [name count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
//top code read data from json and I want when no internet read data from plist 
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Path to the plist (in the application bundle)
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
    @"Plist" ofType:@"plist"];

// Build the array from the plist  
NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

// Show the string values  
for (NSString *str in array2)
  NSLog(@"--%@", str);
```

You have array and now just set the value to datasource array

```
[tableview reloadData];
```

For checking the internet connectivity you can use the [Reachability class provided by apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: my friend how to show in tableView when no internet (how to access in plist file?)

Comment: Why you need internet to access content from your plist file?It's a local file. You can access it anytime.

Comment: @john Tableview has nothing to do with connectivity,For checking availability of connection use Reachability class.Edited the answer with link

Comment: my friend my need internet to check plist if plist isn't equal with url update it and I need show tableview from plist

Comment: you can edit the question and add what specifically you need. It is   important to point correctly what you need.Welcome to SO .Please read the FAQ

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Check Whether Internet is Connected OR Not using Following method, Implement this method

```
- (BOOL) connectedToInternet
{
    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:requestURL];

    return ([data bytes]>0) ? YES : NO;
}
```

OR

Step 1 : You can also Implement Reachability Class to check Internet Connectivity by Apple if you Know it.

Step 2 : Now Make check for Connectivity In your Method Befor invoking Webservice Request

```
if([self connectedToInternet])
{
    // Make a reqeust to server
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourDomain.com/test.php"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [con start];
}
else
{
    // Write a Handy code to load Data from Your Local Plist
    // Path to plist From Documents Folder
    NSString *docFilePath = [DOC_DIR stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

    NSDictionary *dictData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:docFilePath];


    NSLog(@"%@",dictData);
    // Reload your TableView
}
```

Comment: thank you my friend can you help me and tell how I can call .plist file from Document Folder and store in NSDictionary?